# Changing body styles in Nuxt/Vue template

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to add body styles to my template in Nuxt, but I am running into issues.

I am trying to use the `beforeCreate` call, but when I do, I run into the error: document is not defined.

I would like to maintain SSR.  How can I add styling on the body element?

```
<script scoped>
  export default {
    head() {
      return {
        script: [
          {
            src: '/js/vendor/jquery.min.js' 
          },
          {
            src: '/js/site.js' 
          }
        ]
        
      }
    },
    beforeCreate: function() {
        document.body.className = 'service';
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
@import '~/assets/css/style.min.css';
</style>
```

### Update

I added this:

```
head() {
      return {
        script: [
          {
            src: '/js/vendor/jquery.min.js' 
          },
          {
            src: '/js/site.js' 
          }
        ],
        bodyAttrs: {
          class: 'service',
        }
        
      }
    }
```

The tag does get added to the body:

```
<body class="service" data-n-head="%7B%22class%22:%7B%22ssr%22:%22service%22%7D%7D" style="zoom: 1;">
```

However, the styling does not?

```
body.service{padding-top:80px}
body.service{font-family:'Geomanist', sans-serif;color:#000}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because your style is scoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can add:

```
bodyAttrs: {
  class: 'hidden',
},
```

in `nuxt.config.js`

---

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61613138/2333214), you can create an `app.html` file at the root  of your application with following content. I've added the class directly to the `<body>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }} class="service">
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any other way to add this body class without the app.html solution or using a global solution (I want it only on this view).

Comment: @user1072337 see this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5023, it looks like you can register a "plugin" what does something on `window.onNuxtReady`

Comment: @user1072337  also found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59576303/2333214

Comment: So I added the bodyAttrs, but the styling still doesn't get added?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way handling this is using nuxt layouts (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/layouts/). Basically you can define your global html or body styles inside `style` secion of the layout file (which is also a vue file) and then use that layout with your pages (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-layout/)